# Curiosity of newArrayList(E... elements) in google guava lib

Tags: java, collections, guava

This code is simple code of guava library.

I did simplify for easy reading, orginal code see => [link](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.guava/guava/14.0.1/com/google/common/collect/Lists.java#Lists.newArrayList%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)

```
// Case A
public static <E> ArrayList<E> newArrayList(E... elements) {
    int capacity = computeArrayListCapacity(elements.length);
    ArrayList<E> list = new ArrayList<E>(capacity);
    Collections.addAll(list, elements);
    return list;
}

static int computeArrayListCapacity(int arraySize) {
    long value = 5L + arraySize + (arraySize / 10);
    if (value > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
    if (value < Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
        return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    }
    return (int) value;
}
```

Why set capacity to **5L + arraySize + (arraySize / 10)**?

And What are different between 3 cases(A,B,C)?

```
//Case B
public static <E> ArrayList<E> newArrayList(E... elements) {
    ArrayList<E> list = new ArrayList<E>(elements.length);
    Collections.addAll(list, elements);
    return list;
}

//Case C
public static <E> ArrayList<E> newArrayList(E... elements) {
    ArrayList<E> list = new ArrayList<E>();
    Collections.addAll(list, elements);
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Well it creates a new ArrayList which has a little bit of extra capacity. As a list is usually used when you have data with dynamic count, this has the benefit that the list does not need a costly resizing when the next element is added (case b).
Resizing is expensive, because it is done by creating a new (bigger) array and copying all existing elements into that new array.

Comment: The part of you question with `Integer.MIN_VALUE` is misleading, I'd suggest to remove it (it's not exact, anyway, since `saturatedCast` never does both tests.

Comment: @maaartinus Yes, I did not use computeArrayListCapacity method. It is just code in guava-Ints.java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not much to add to Matthias' comment:

Case A is optimal when the list later grows, but not much: less than 10% plus 5 more elements. If it never grows, you're wasting some memory. If it grows more, some resizing will occur, but in general there's nothing anybody could do about it.

Case B is optimal in the improbable case the list doesn't grow. But this is improbable, as usually the `ImmutableList` can be used instead.

Case C first allocates an array of 10 elements, which may be then replaced multiple times in `Collections.addAll`. IIUIC it happens twice for `elements.length==16` (namely `10 -> 15 -> 22` since the ArrayList's growth factor is 1.5).

Comment: This. You can see that `5L + arraySize + (arraySize / 10)` has a "`TODO: Figure out the right behavior, and document it`" comment next to it which basically means that the expression isn't backed by rigorous research. It's meant to allow some additions to the list and it's most likely empirical (random). The `5` there is for small lists (with `length` around 10 since they wouldn't get anything from `length / 10`), the `length / 10` is there for big lists (`length` in hundreds or thousands, since for them, 5 is nothing).

Comment: Agreed with everything. I'd also add that there's no reason for not saving some 40 cycles by using `arraySize >> 3` instead of the division (or maybe `arraySize >> 4`, both 1/8 and 1/16 are close enough to 1/10).